# In github actions, mvn install says that pom.xml does not exist

Tags: maven, github, github-actions

Here is my repository: https://github.com/klashdevelopment/klashitemsystem

I'm trying to get the GitHub action in there to work (i am brand new to GitHub actions) What I want to do in my action is: when there is a push, run mvn install and release the jar file to releases. I'm not too sure how to do this, and I tried to smash together a few other people's GitHub actions to do what I want. When I run this, however, it says that no pom.xml exists (when it does exist in the repository) I even tried setting the working directory. Anyone know why?

`Error:  The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (D:\a\klashitemsystem\klashitemsystem). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]`

Workflow:

```yaml
    steps:
    - name: Set up JDK
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 17

    - name: Packaging Jar
      id: packaging-jar
      shell: bash
      run: |
        cd .
        mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check out your code. Add this step:

```yaml
    steps:
    - name: Check out Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: 17

    - name: Packaging Jar
      id: packaging-jar
      shell: bash
      run: mvn clean install
```