# How can I edit and delete files with github actions Workflow and push changes in github in develop branch

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions

I would delete some files in my Github repository with Github Actions workflow, then commit and push my changes in my Github repository, I try something like this :

```
name: Template Cleanup
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  clean:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Clean secret management files
      run: |
        rm -f \
          .github/file.yaml \
          .github/file2.yaml \
          .github/.gpg \
          .github/workflows/workflow.yaml \
          .sops.yaml
    - name: Commit files and push it
      run: |
        git config --global user.email "email@gmail.com"
        git config --global user.name "github actions"
        git add .
        git commit -m "chore: clean repo"
        git push
```

but I have Error

```
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Do you know how can I do that ? thanks

Comment: You have a typo. You're missing a `\ ` after `.github/.gpg`, so the shell is looking for a *command* named `.github/workflows/workflow.yaml`.

Comment: @larsks you right, after correcting this I get fatal error in commit and push files step, I updated my question

Comment: It doesn't look like you've ever checked out your repository (using the `actions/checkout@v3` action).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In github actions, mvn install says that pom.xml does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73215520/in-github-actions-mvn-install-says-that-pom-xml-does-not-exist)